# How to keep the shape of original list when we're using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, numpy, list-comprehension, shapes

I have a list of zeros with the shape like below:

```
yp = numpy.zeros(5, 2, 2), dtype = complex)
```

I modified it using two for loops as below:

```
for a in range(0,5):
    for b in range(0, 2):
        yp[a, b, b] = numpy.sum(F[a, b,:])
```

How can I do the same thing using list comprehension?
Obviously, using the line below will change the shape of my original list.

```
yp = [numpy.sum(F[a, b,:]) for a in range(0,5) for b in range(0, 2)]
```

Comment: Make a nested list: `[[numpy.sum(y_network[a, b,:]) for b in rang(2)] for a in range(0,5)] `

Comment: Makes the numbers no longer complex @hpaulj

Comment: @hpaulj I tried it but didn't work, it still doesn't return a list with a shape like (5,2,2) that some of its elements have been changes.

Comment: Lists have `len`, not shape.

Comment: @hpaulj So, maybe list comprehension cannot be used in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original loop cannot be converted to a list comprehension because it doesn't assign all elements of the numpy matrix.  A list comprehension always produces a complete list (or list of lists).

If you goal is to fill the non assigned elements with zeroes, then the corresponding the list comprehension could be something like this:

```
[ [ [0,0,numpy.sum(y_network[a, b, :])] for b in range(2)] for a in range(5)]
```

The difference is that each level of comprehension produces a list which itself uses a comprehension for its elements.

Note that this doesn't do exactly the same thing because the value of `numpy.sum(y_network[a, b, :])` is always placed in the last element of the 3rd dimension instead of at index `b`.  You could use some more code to fill with zeros left and right but that will make it complicated and unreadable which would pretty much defeat the purpose of using a list comprehension.

You could also write a single loop for the assignment:

```
for b in range(2): yl[:,b,b] = np.sum(network[:,b,:],1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you only assign [a,b,b] (diagonals of 2 by 2 matrix) and leave the rest as is and it's hard to do that in list comprehension. The following will do the same as what you have, but inefficiently.

```
yp = numpy.array([numpy.sum(y_network[a, b,:]) if b==c else yp[a,b,b] for a in range(0,5) for b in range(0, 2) for c in range(0,2)]).reshape(5,2,2)
```

Or you could insert `yp[a,b,b]` after

```
yp = [numpy.sum(y_network[a, b,:]) for a in range(0,5) for b in range(0, 2)]
```

at the correct indexes to make it more efficient, but the nested loop you have should be better.